# Windows Phone 8 SpeechSynthesizer Pause

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, speech-synthesis, speechsynthesizer

I'm developing an app where I would like to pause in between when the SpeechSynthesizer.SpeakTextAsync is running and resume back from there.

```
await synthesizer.SpeakTextAsync(text);
```

stop reading when `var stop = true;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some one posted here a while back, at the same time I refreshed the page, read his answer, saw a notification & refreshed the page again & the answer was gone. But whoever posted, he is a life saver. It stuck my mind and I ended up creating this.

```
    String text;  // your text to read out loud
    String[] parts = text.Split(' ');
    int max = parts.Length;
    int count = 0;

    private String makeSSML() {
        if (count == max) { 
            count= 0;
        }
        String s = "<speak version=\"1.0\" ";
        s += "xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis\" xml:lang=\"en-US\">";
        for (int i = count; i < max; i++)
        {
            s += parts[i];
            s += "<mark name=\"anything\"/>";
        }
        s += "<mark name=\"END\"/>";
        s += "</speak>";
        return s;
    }

    private void playIT(){
        synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();
        synth.BookmarkReached += synth_BookmarkReached;
        synth.SpeakSsmlAsync(makeSSML());
    }

    private void synth_BookmarkReached(object sender, SpeechBookmarkReachedEventArgs e)
    {
        count++;
        if (e.Bookmark == "END") {
            synth.Dispose();
        }
    }

    private void Pause_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        synth.Dispose();
    }
```

Thanks man, your answer gave me the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Well, according to the documentation, when you call `CancellAll`, you're cancelling the Tasks that are executing asynchronously. By contract, this results in an `OperationCancelledException` being thrown. That means that wherever you call SpeakTextAsync, SpeakSsmlAsync or SpeakSsmlFromUriAsync, you must surround these calls with a try/catch statement to prevent this exception from going uncaught.

**Example:**

```
private static SpeechSynthesizer synth;

public async static Task<SpeechSynthesizer> SpeechSynth(string dataToSpeak)
        {
            synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();
            IEnumerable<VoiceInformation> englishVoices = from voice in InstalledVoices.All
                                                          where voice.Language == "en-US"
                                                          && voice.Gender.Equals(VoiceGender.Female)
                                                          select voice;
            if (englishVoices.Count() > 0)
            {
                synth.SetVoice(englishVoices.ElementAt(0));
            }

            await synth.SpeakTextAsync(dataToSpeak); 

            return synth;
        }  


public static void CancelSpeech()
        {
            synth.CancelAll();
        }
```

Now call the `SpeechSynth("Some Data to Speak")` where you want, and whenever you want to cancel it, just call `CancelSpeech()`.

Its Done! Enjoy...!